# Latex Coding for Table

Tags: tables

```
  \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\begin {document}
\begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{llllll|lllllllll}
    \hline
    ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ \\ \hline
    ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ \\
    ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ \\
    ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ \\
    ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ \\
    ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ \\
    ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ \\
    ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ \\
    ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ \\
    ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ \\
    ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**How to Create a blank row like now no 2? 
I mean which  code is need to be added? 
How to bold the line three times and margin the cell space??**

Comment: why should it _not_ be supported??

Comment: Looks horrible, but it does compile!

Comment: Thanks  it worked, can you please see  the updated question.

Comment: You need to use `\multicolumn{15}{|l|}{<stuff>}`

Comment: Can you please  insert   that in my latex code, hence I will get completely?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is more like your drawing, it should give you the idea.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\begin {document}

\begin{tabular}{|l|*{4}l|*{10}{l}|}
\hline
~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{~} & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ \\
\hline
\multicolumn{15}{|l|}{~} \\
\hline
~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ \\
\hline
~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ \\
~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ \\
~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ \\
~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ \\
~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ \\
~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ \\
~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ \\
~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ \\
~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]